# Haskell: Non-exhaustive patterns in stack

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, runtime-error

I have the following stack class:

```
newtype Stack my_stack = Stack [my_stack] deriving Show

getSize :: Stack my_stack -> Int 
getSize (Stack []) = 0
getSize (Stack (x:xs)) = 1 + getSize (Stack xs)

push :: my_stack -> Stack my_stack -> Stack my_stack
push x (Stack xs) = Stack (x:xs)

pop :: Stack my_stack -> Stack my_stack
pop (Stack (x:xs)) = Stack xs

getTop :: Stack my_stack -> my_stack
getTop (Stack (x:xs)) = x
```

however when I try to use the `getTop` function, I get the `Non-exhaustive patterns in function getTop` error. How can I declare the base case (which I assume is empty case?) for the `getTop` function so I won't be getting non-exhaustive pattern errors? Thank you!

Comment: voting to close as OP is asking multiple questions in comment threads, and therefor degrading future utility.

Comment: @MichaelLitchard If you deem a comment inappropriate, flag the comment. It doesn't take away from the utility of the question itself in the slightest.

Comment: @SilvioMayolo good point, removing close vote.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your function is unsafe right now. That warning is (correctly) notifying you that you don't handle the empty-stack case. Now, the question is: what do you want to do if the user calls `getTop` with an empty stack? You've got a few options. I'll sort them in roughly descending order of my preference.

## 1. Return `Maybe`

If we have a value that may or may not exist, the idiomatic approach is to return `Maybe`. `Maybe` is a special type that may or may not contain a value, and it's up to the caller to decide what to do with it. They might themselves opt to return a `Maybe`, or they might provide a default value, or they might just show the user an error. But the type system will enforce that they handle the situation.

```
getTop :: Stack my_stack -> Maybe my_stack
getTop (Stack []) = Nothing
getTop (Stack (x:xs)) = Just x
```

This is perfectly safe and gives the caller total control.

## 2. Force the user to provide a default value

Instead, you can require the user to specify the value they want if the stack is empty.

```
getTop :: my_stack -> Stack my_stack -> my_stack
getTop orelse (Stack []) = orelse
getTop _ (Stack (x:xs)) = x
```

This is still perfectly safe, like the previous solution, but in my opinion it's more awkward than an `Option`. The type signature `Stack my_stack -> Maybe my_stack` is very clearly indicative of what the function does: it takes a stack and might return a value from it. The type signature `my_stack -> Stack my_stack -> my_stack` is more nebulous: are we adding a value to the stack, are we returning a default, what are we doing? Further, if the user actually *wants* a `Maybe`, there may not be a suitable default value that's distinguishable from "nothing was on the stack".

## 3. Throw an error

This is *not* idiomatic Haskell and I do *not* recommend doing it in production. But if you're just writing some short code for personal practice, it can be useful for hacking.

```
getTop :: Stack my_stack -> my_stack
getTop (Stack []) = error "Empty stack in getTop"
getTop (Stack (x:xs)) = x
```

`error` is a special function that has signature `String -> a` (for any `a`). You provide it with an error message and it... well, it crashes your program. There are technically ways of catching an `error`, but they're awkward and have a lot of difficult quirks, so generally you should regard `error` as a hard crash and only use it if there's *no* possibility for recovery. Hence, I don't recommend it in this case, as "the stack was empty" is very much a recoverable condition.

Comment: And would there be any easy solution if I want to return an empty string when getting the top of empty stack?

Comment: As your code is written right now, the stack may contain any data type (`my_stack` is a type variable), not just strings. So there's no guarantee that `""` is a valid return value. However, if you go with Option 1 above, then you can call it as `maybe "" id (getTop stack)` to provide the default value

Comment: oh I see, but I now for sure that my stack will only include strings, how can I modify it so that it is string stack - making it easier to guarantee "" return value

Comment: One question at a time. If you have multiple questions, open another question up.

Answer (score 1):

This declaration:

```
getTop (Stack (x:xs)) = x
```

It means: "when `getTop`'s parameter is a `Stack` that contains a list that consists of a head `x` and tail `xs`, the result is `x`"

But what if the parameter is a `Stack` that contains an empty list? You haven't defined what should happen in that case, and so an error happens.

So you need a pattern match for that case:

```
getTop (Stack (x:xs)) = x
getTop (Stack []) = ???
```

But here's the question: what should the result of `getTop` be in that case? Only you can decide that, based on your particular situation. For what it's worth, a common pattern is to return a `Maybe my_stack` instead:

```
getTop :: Stack my_stack -> Maybe my_stack
getTop (Stack (x:xs)) = Just x
getTop (Stack []) = Nothing
```

Comment: thank you so much for you comment, well in my case I realised that the most suited behavior would be to get an empty string but `getStackPeek (Stack []) = ""` yields error, what should I put on the right hand side so it wouldn't yield error and that I would get empty string

Comment: The type `my_stack` is not necessarily a string. If you want to return a string, then the type of `getTop` should be `Stack String -> String`